# Entity Framework code-first is not generating migration

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

My application is targeting an existing database. After I've added this class `passwordhistory`. I created a migrations, but I got a couple of empty methods:

```
public partial class passwordhistory : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
    }
}
```

When I tried to run `update-database`, I got an error saying that **db.AspNetRoles** table existed already. I read somewhere, someone said that I should run:

`Add-Migration InitialCreate –IgnoreChanges`

Now I'm trying to create another migration to take into account the new class I just create, I'm getting again just those empty **up** and **down** methods. I don't even see a **PasswordHistory** table in the database.

How to force EF to generate migration?

Here's my model

```
public class PasswordHistory
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public DateTime ChangeDate { get; set; }
}

public class PasswordHistoryMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<PasswordHistory>
{
    public PasswordHistoryMap()
    {
        ToTable("PasswordHistory");

        HasKey(h => h.id);

        Property(h => h.UserId)
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar(max)");

        Property(h => h.Password)
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar")
            .HasMaxLength(128);

    }
}
```

Here's my dbcontext class

```
public class myDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public myDbContext()
        : base("myConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<PasswordHistory> PasswordsHistory { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PasswordHistoryMap());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }

    public static myDbContext Create()
    {
        return new myDbContext();
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Can you show more code, for example, your `DbSet` declaration or your DbContext class? And wich version of EF are you using?

Comment: Plus see the dbcontext class definition

Comment: You can comment your `DbSet`declaration and `modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new PasswordHistoryMap());` lines. Create a migration with -IgnoreChanges flag. Then uncomment these lines and create a new migration. Maybe is not the better solution, but it works...

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked.